# Create Git commits and push to GitHub with Ruby

Tags: ruby, git, github

I am working on a web application where a user will modify a file (hosted on GitHub) and should have the ability to save directly to GitHub.

I don't need to handle this client-side so a server-side Ruby solution would be fine. I'm assuming I would need to work with some sort of GitHub API.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Were you ever able to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The [ruby git gem](https://github.com/schacon/ruby-git) is what you need. It can do virtually anything you want with a local or remote git repository, including new commits, diffs, branches, tags, pushing to GitHub, you name it.

Answer (score 0):

Search google for "ruby github gem" and "ruby git gem".  If not found, use `system("git...")` to invoke the git command line utility.